# IDE controller on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I've a problem with virtualbox. I'm using it on a CentOS server (no GUI) to virtualize machines that will be used from clients with remote desktop connection.

I'm trying to attach an ISO file to a vm with this command:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "intouch" --dvd /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
```

but it responds

```
VBoxManage: error: No drive attached to device slot 0 on port 1 of controller 'IDE Controller'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
Context: "MountMedium(Bstr("IDE Controller").raw(), 1, 0, dvdMedium, FALSE )" at line 962 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

So I tried to attach an IDE controller

```
VBoxManage storagectl "intouch" --add ide --name "IDE Controller"
```

But it said

```
VBoxManage: error: Storage controller named 'IDE Controller' already exists
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
Context: "AddStorageController(Bstr(pszCtl).raw(), StorageBus_IDE, ctl.asOutParam())" at line 1008 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command you are searching for is:

```
 VBoxManage storageattach TheNameOfYourVM --storagectl "IDE Controller"     --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
```

If this does not work immediately, try it follwoing this example which works for me:

```
   $ VBoxManage storagectl JH --name "IDE Controller" --remove 
   $ VBoxManage storagectl JH --name "IDE Controller" --add ide
   $ VBoxManage storageattach JH --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
   $
```

Comment: Just a doubt: what "JH" stands for?

Comment: @MaxMarkson Sorry, I forgot, it's the name of one of **my** VMs, the one with which I tested the commands above, since I was not sure I remembered the exact syntax.

Comment: I supposed it but I asked anyway...just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and checking for the file `action_provision` did the trick for me

```
if ! File.exist?(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/action_provision")
    vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "IDE Controller", "--add", "ide"]
end
```

After provisioning vagrant creates that file. On the second boot it is already in place. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855635/check-if-vagrant-provisioning-has-been-done)